# Estimando o tempo de resposta de um servidor usando Python ou regex

Tags: python, regex

Criei um ambiente virtualizado com um servidor Apache (rodando em Debian) e várias máquinas atacantes rodando Debian também. Foi utilizado o VMware Workstation.

IP do servidor: 192.168.91.5

Tenho arquivo de dump (PCAP) coletado com o tcpdump. Há alguma forma de estimar (ou calcular) o tempo de resposta do servidor a cada 60 segundos?
Os IPs dos atacantes são da forma 192.168.91.X

Exemplo de arquivo PCAP:

[image: PCAP]

Arquivos PCAP de exemplo:

https://ufile.io/hfqp4

Tentei usar [tcprstat](https://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/tcprstat_start.html) mas o resutado sempre dá zero, o que sem dúvidas, está errado:

```
tcprstat -r semAtaques.pcap -f '%n\n' -p 80 -t 1 -n 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar usar libs prontas pra isto, encontrei duas:

### [pypcapfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcapfile)

Para instalar use o `pip`:

```
pip install pypcapfile
```

Um exemplo de uso:

```
from pcapfile import savefile
testcap = open('1.pcap', 'rb')
capfile = savefile.load_savefile(testcap, verbose=True)
print capfile
```

### [pcap-parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pcap-parser)

Para instalar use o `pip`:

```
pip install pcap-parser
```

Ele funciona por linha de comando (o que pode ser aproveitado), exemplo simples:

```
parse_pcap 1.pcap
```

A lista dos outros comandos estão em https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pcap-parser

Comment: Obrigado! Este parece que não gera estatísticas! Estou tentando entender pq tcprstat está dando sempre zero!

Comment: Estou testando também este:  http://yconalyzer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: yconalyzer não consegui instalar

Comment: eu não entendi como conseguir o tempo de resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Conseguir resolver utilizando um programa free:

Response Time Viewer for Wireshark:

http://www.solarwinds.com/free-tools/response-time-viewer-for-wireshark

Ele fornece, dentre outras coisas, o tempo de resposta da aplicação e da rede!